# gcc: how to detect bad `bool` usage

Tags: c, gcc, clang, static-analysis

Is there some way to detect the bad usage of `bool` values in code like

```
#include <stdbool.h>

void *foo(void)
{
    return false;
}

int bar(void)
{
    return true;
}
```

Both functions are accepted by `gcc` (8.3.1) and `clang` (7.0.1) without any warnings

```
$ gcc -Wall -W -pedantic -c x.c
$ clang -Xclang -analyzer-checker=alpha --analyze  -Wall -W -pedantic -c x.c
$ clang -Wall -W -pedantic -c x.c
$
```

Compiling as C++ code would detect the problem in `foo()` but is not an option but rest of code is C, not C++.

Are there other (`-W`) options or switches which would create diagnostics for these cases?

Comment: Would lint catch these? Especially an updated tool such as PCLint? See for instance https://invisible-island.net/personal/lint-tools.html and see this about lint http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/lint.html

Comment: Looks like there is an updated version, splint, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881269/how-do-i-download-and-install-lint

Comment: @RichardChambers thinks for the hint; but "splint" does not seem to understand C99+ at all and aborts when seeing variadic macros (e.g. `#define log_err(_fmt, ...)`).

Answer (score 2):

Make the example less trivial:

```
bool x;

void *foo(void)
{
    return x;
}

int bar(void)
{
    return x;
}
```

and it want compile at all.

usually true and false are just definitions and have value `1` and `0`

From the stdbool.h header file

```
#ifndef _STDBOOL_H
#define _STDBOOL_H

#ifndef __cplusplus

#define bool    _Bool
#define true    1
#define false   0

#else /* __cplusplus */
```

in **your** first example you just return zero and most compilers will not warn as they treat it as NULL. Try to return `true` and you will get the warning.

Comment: My code is some simplified variant of refactored code where functions previously returned a `bool` value and where converted to return richer values.  The `return true` resp. `return false` was missed in the refactoring and stayed literally;  I just want to detect them.

Comment: Just don't include stdbool.h (you don't need it), and you'll catch *all*  the occurences.

Comment: @wildplasser or if stdbool.h is buried deeper, a temporary local redefinition to "break" `bool`, `true` and `false` could also help identify the places to change. (don't leave it like that, but...)

Comment: @wildplasser Not a good idea. In my experience, using `stdbool.h` can significantly increase code readability, simply because booleans are labeled as such. Of course, I would have preferred a definition like `((_Bool)0)`, but I've never run into the OP's problem (even though I'm making liberal use of `stdbool.h`).

Answer (score 2):

C defines the `<stdbool.h>` macros `true` and `false` as expanding to integer constant expressions of value `1` and `0` respectively. Since they're `int`s and `bool` (`_Bool`) in itself is an integer type, any such usage is equally valid. Even the value of the boolean expressions in C is an `int` and not a `bool`, so there is not much help for you with the `bar` function.

However, `foo` is a different beast - if the return value were `true` then it would be caught right away because `1` is not convertible to a pointer. `false`, having the *integer constant value `0`* is *a* null-pointer constant and will be converted to null pointer. You could perhaps catch the incorrect use by replacing the `#include <stdbool.h>` with something that does the inclusion but defines `false` as say `0.0` which is a falsy value but not an integer constant expression.